# Stop after refresh post-back in asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net project. I have a search textbox in it. when I search first time it work properly. Then after refresh the page textbox value is not clearing.

```js
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {                
                txtEmployeeID.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            txtEmployeeID.Focus();                        
        }
```

Comment: Are you using any button to submit ? Or how you are posting back the search query to the server ?

Comment: No, there is no any button. but I used TextChanged event in that textbox

Comment: Set the Autopostback property on the textbox to true.

Comment: @akemp 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpID" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtEmployeeID_TextChanged" MaxLength="8" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
this is the text box I used.

Comment: Add that property on your textbox declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just refreshing by pressing F5 or Ctrl + R then it is considered as just a page refresh.
There is a difference in refresh and a postback.

Please refer the below article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68371/Detecting-Refresh-or-Postback-in-ASP-NET

Comment: refreshing the page causes postback in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

try this code
in your mark up set autopostback in your textbox as true

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(Page.IsPostBack)
          {                
            txtEmployeeID.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        txtEmployeeID.Focus();  

 }
```

just remove "!" in your if statement, or remove the if statement.